# How does center_box parameter of sklearn.datasets.make_blob() work?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I was searching online about how `center_box` parameter works in `sklearn.datasets.make_blobs()`. However, I could not find any good answer about it.

How does this parameter affect the sample dataset generation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_blobs.html):

> `center_box`: tuple of float (min, max), default=(-10.0, 10.0)
> The bounding box for each cluster center when centers are generated at random.

This means that the parameter `center_box` is an area of how big a cluster will be.